# Why isn't this UIScrollView autolayout working?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have a simple program with a `UIScrollView`, and one `UITextField` inside it.  I constrain the `UIScrollView` to have 0 space on all it's four sides, which I thought would make it fill the screen.  And I constrain the text field to be the standard space from the edges:

[image]

But when it runs, it does this:

[image]

I see the [technical note](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html), but I don't understand it yet.

The field will fill the screen if I give a width=280 constraint, but that goes against the spirit of autolayout. I want it to adapt to the width of the screen, not be hard coded to the 280pt width in the storyboard.  How to do that?

Here are the layout errors:

[image]

Comment: Can you show the error warning from your Xcode? It seems that you don't have enough constraint for your text field. You have enough constraint in horizon direction but not in vertical

Comment: Added the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my own question.

The answer is contained in the tech note, but in my opinion not explained in enough detail. This blog post helped me: http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/05/uiscrollview-autolayout-ios/

Summary: put a width constraint on the text field to shut up the IB errors, but then check the "Placeholder, remove at build time" checkbox for the constraint (in the attribute inspector in IB).  Then you can add better constraints programmatically, in the view controller's `viewDidLoad` method. In this case I want constraints that connect the text field's left and right edges to the scroll view's superview edges (and thus the screen edges). You apparently can't make constraints like this in IB. With those two constraints, it all works correctly, even as the screen is rotated.